# How to rollback in Liquibase when using Docker for deployment

Tags: liquibase

I started using Liquibase for one of our Spring Boot project. Using Gitlab CI, we are creating the image and deploying it. Everything is working fine. But I am stuck at rollback.

I have gone through the [Liquibase rollback documentation](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/rollback.html) but I can perform either using cmd or maven plugin. But the issue in my case is all thing packaged in image and deployed. Their is no system on which I can run these command. So how can I perform the rollback?

I tried running the rollback command from command line, it will not work I guess, because my database is in AWS. And I am accessing that RDS via image file which was build from Gitlab CI.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
java -cp /path-to-your/spring-boot-fat.jar \
    -Dloader.system=true \
    -Dloader.main=liquibase.integration.commandline.Main \
    org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher \
    --changeLogFile=db/changelog/db-changelog-master.xml \
    --driver=org.h2.Driver \
    --username=sa \
    --url="jdbc:h2:~/test;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE" \
    --password=sa \
    updateSQL
```

Of course change the properties for your database and specify properly the path of your changelog on classpath.

### Update

This could help you doing it programmatically:

```
void testRollback(final Connection connection) throws LiquibaseException {
    final Liquibase liquibase = new Liquibase(
            "/path-to/your/changelog.xml",
            new CompositeResourceAccessor(new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(), new FileSystemResourceAccessor()),
            new JdbcConnection(connection));

    final String contexts = "dev,test";
    liquibase.rollback(10, contexts);
}
```

Comment: thank for replying. But running rollback command from command line will not work I guess because my db is in aws. And I am accessing that rds via Image file which was build from Gitlab CI

Comment: What kind of image it is? Is it docker or what?

Comment: Yes. docker image containing .jar of the spring-boot application.

Comment: and it's not possible to get into that docker image in aws? Like in [this post](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-cli/issues/143#issuecomment-373877576)

Comment: No. it is quite hard to get into the docker image as it was consumed by the elastic beanstalk in aws.

Comment: then you can implement liquibase in your application and run rollback on some endpoint.

Comment: That is my question how to do that?

Comment: see update, in `rollback` you can put more parameters, see javadocs.

Comment: did you find a solution ? I'm having the same issue